# MSSQL query in C#, Geting part of WHERE clause from a string

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am using following code:

```
string str = "ID = 15";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * " + 
                                       "FROM Cutomer" + 
                                       " Where (Status='Umbruch') and '"+str+"' " , con))
```

I am getting this error:

```
near 'ID = 15' is a non boolean expression specified in a context where a condition is expected.
```

I know I can use the above code like this:

```
int id = 15; 

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * " + 
                                       "FROM Cutomer" + 
                                       " Where (Status='Umbruch') and (ID='"+str+"')" , con))
```

It works fine like this but I want to use it as mentioned in first code above. Because the number of IDs is not fixed they can be 2,3 or more. Just for simplicity I put my code here like this.

Comment: Because the right usage of this `ID = '15'` not `'ID = 15'` ?

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Can you explain if the ID field is text or numeric?

Comment: @Steve ID field is numeric

Comment: Then you don't need single quotes anywhere in your string used for the where clause. But I repeat again, keep yourself save and use a parameterized query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're making it a literal here:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * " + 
                                       "FROM Cutomer" + 
                                       " Where (Status='Umbruch') and '"+str+"' " , con))
```

It should be:

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * " + 
                                       "FROM Cutomer" + 
                                       " Where (Status='Umbruch') and "+str, con))
```

Note the slight difference in which the `'` were removed.

Further, please [read through my blog post](http://learncsharp.org/how-to-properly-and-safely-access-a-database-with-ado-net/) on why you're open to SQL injection and why you need to leverage parameterized SQL instead of raw SQL.

Comment: @SLaks: Are you referring to the fact that the `str` should be `ID = '15'`? Which would only be true if the key were in fact a `VARCHAR` yes? In other words `ID = 15` wouldn't work if the key were a `VARCHAR`, but either would work if it were an `INT`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud It not working like this I am having a syntax error, at  + strr +, con)). The error is: invalid expression term ','

Comment: @Kami, is it the extraneous `+` after the `str` variable that I missed on my first edit?

Answer (score 1):

The first version should be (from your second "working" query, you need simple quotes around 15, not around the entire expression).

```
str = "ID = '15'";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * " + 
                                       "FROM Cutomer" + 
                                       " Where (Status='Umbruch') and "+str , con))
```

By the way, you should user Parameters, not direct strings.

If you need an IN clause, you may look at that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842263/an-issue-of-sqlcommand-with-parameters-for-in)

Answer (score 1):

A simple error, do not put single quotes before and after the string

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Cutomer " + 
                                       "WHERE (Status='Umbruch') AND " + str , con))
```

of course this assumes that your ID field is numeric and not a text field.
In the latter case you should put the single quotes around the 15 constant

```
string str = "ID = '15'";
```

As a side note, keep in mind that string concatenation is really dangerous because your code could be exploited with a simple [Sql Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) attack. In this very specific case there is no possibility for injection.

If you receive the ID to search for from a user input, do not use string concatenation to build sql commands. Instead use a parameterized query

```
 using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Cutomer " + 
                               " Where (Status='Umbruch') and ID=@custID" , con))
 {
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custID", 15);
      ......
 }
```