# sql where clause with multiple conditions c# web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, where-clause

I am creating a web app in c#, and I have multiple id's.

This is how it looks:

```
string id = "17359,17355,17460,16834";
```

this is four different id's i stored in my string

now this is my sqlcommand

```
sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand("select * from trid where id!=@id",con);
sqlparameter[] param={
new sqlparameter("@id",id)
};
```

what i want is, i dont want data's with these id's  `17359,17355,17460,16834`

and i want to see the rest of the data

what i should do here??

id's are dynamic and can be less or more in numbers

Comment: Split the string and build the command from there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a function which will split your string and return the individual values which you can use in select statement like [select * from SELECT * FROM trid WHERE id NOT IN (select ID from dbo.splitcommaSep(@IDs))]

Kindly review following link for the function

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Split-and-convert-Comma-Separated-Delimited-String-to-Table-in-SQL-Server.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If your IDs are comma-separated, you can do it like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from trid where id NOT IN (@id)", con);
```

So you don't have to split the ID-string.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a dynamic way to do this but this will work if the ID's you don't want to see are static.

```
string id1 = "17359";
string id2 = "17355";
string id3 = "17460";
string id4 = "16834";

sqlcommand cmd=new sqlcommand("SELECT * FROM trid WHERE id NOT IN (@id1, @id2, @id3, @id4)",con);
sqlparameter[] param={
new sqlparameter("@id",id)
};
```

Comment: id's are dynamic and can be more then this

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16842263/an-issue-of-sqlcommand-with-parameters-for-in

Comment: If that link solves the issue close it as a dupe